# Using Fonet to Convert XSL-FO to PDF Getting System Exception: Unknown enumerated value for property 'text-decoration': no-underline

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, xsl-fo

I'm using Fonet to convert XSL-FO to Pdf. Below is the code I'm using C# on Visual Studio

```
FonetDriver driver = FonetDriver.Make();
driver.Render("C:\\XSLT\\Input\\input.fo", "C:\\XSLT\\Output\\result.pdf");
```

Getting Exception:

```
System.SystemException: **'System.SystemException: Unknown enumerated value for property 'text-decoration': no-underline** 
   at Fonet.FonetDriver.FireFonetError(String message)
   at Fonet.Fo.EnumProperty.Maker.CheckEnumValues(String value)
   at Fonet.Fo.Properties.TextDecorationMaker.CheckEnumValues(String value)
   at Fonet.Fo.PropertyMaker.Make(PropertyList propertyList, String value, FObj fo)
   at Fonet.Fo.PropertyListBuilder.MakeList(String ns, String elementName, Attributes attributes, FObj parentFO)
   at Fonet.Fo.FOTreeBuilder.StartElement(String uri, String localName, Attributes attlist)
   at Fonet.Fo.FOTreeBuilder.Parse(XmlReader reader)'
```

Example <fo:block> in my input.fo

[image]

Help!

Comment: Are you sure that there is no `no-underline` in your XSL-FO? Is there only one `fo:block` in your FO document. If not, consider trying with a document that has only one `fo:block`. I hope that the problem is not caused by the space in `text-decoration="underline "`.

Comment: I have no-underline too. There is more fo:block for a sample I given one. Tried without giving space in text-decoration="underline", "no-underline" Still it's not generating

Comment: Have you removed the `fo:block` that contains `no-underline`?

Comment: I have more `fo:block` with `text-decoration="no-underline" `

Comment: If you remove those, do you still get the error message?  Would it produce the correct result if you changed `no-underline` to be `none`?